# How to round the double value upto two decimal points in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, double, decimal-point

I have made this method that was called to perform functionality and do calculation but return number in double format for some calculations upto more than 10 decimal points. How can i make this code to show only upto 2 or 3 decimal points?

```
getProductPrice(int productID) {
    var cart = cartlist.firstWhere((cart) => cart.product.id == productID,
        orElse: () => null);
    if (cart != null) {
      var price= (cart.count)*(cart.product.price);
      return price;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      return 0.0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: see `double.toStringAs*()` methods

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `String toStringAsFixed(int fractionDigits)`

- Returns a decimal-point string-representation of this.
- Converts `this` to a double before computing the string representation.
- If the absolute value of this is greater or equal to 10^21 then this methods returns an exponential representation computed by this.toStringAsExponential(). Otherwise the result is the closest string representation with exactly fractionDigits digits after the decimal point. If fractionDigits equals 0 then the decimal point is omitted.
- The parameter fractionDigits must be an integer satisfying: 0 <= fractionDigits <= 20.

Examples:

```
1.toStringAsFixed(3);  // 1.000
(4321.12345678).toStringAsFixed(3);  // 4321.123
(4321.12345678).toStringAsFixed(5);  // 4321.12346
123456789012345678901.toStringAsFixed(3);  // 123456789012345683968.000
1000000000000000000000.toStringAsFixed(3); // 1e+21
5.25.toStringAsFixed(0); // 5
```

For more information check out official [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html).